# Missing Push Notification Entitlement warning mail from apple

Tags: ios

**Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app registers with the Apple Push Notification Service, but the application signature's entitlements do not include the required "aps-environment" entitlement. Make sure you have enabled Push Notification Services for this app, and that you have downloaded a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement.**

But i havent use push notification to my project. Now i was not able to see my + symbol for build to submit my app in app store. Now what should i do ???